# Animated PNG to canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am using a script to copy an animated PNG, put it to canvas to use a chromakey filter.

Everything seems to be working, but I don't get the image copied to the canvas to animate.

I am using DrawImage, which is where it goes wrong. I've been trial and erroring for a while, but I just don't understand how to not convert an animated PNG to a static PNG.

```
$(function(){
    var img = $("#source").get(0);
    var $canvasbg = $("<div id='target-container' />");
    var canvas = $("<canvas class='greenscreen'></canvas>").get(0);
    $canvasbg.append(canvas);
    $('#container').append($canvasbg);
    img.onload = function() {
        greenScreen(img, canvas, $canvasbg);
    };

});

function greenScreen(img, canvas, $container, bg) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = img.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = img.clientHeight;
    $container.width(img.clientWidth);
    $container.height(img.clientHeight);
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var data = imageData.data;
    var start = {
        red: data[0],
        green: data[1],
        blue: data[2]
    };


    // iterate over all pixels
    for(var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
        var diff = Math.abs(data[i] - data[0]) + Math.abs(data[i+1] - data[1]) + Math.abs(data[i+2] - data[2]);
        data[i + 3] = (diff*diff)/$('#tolerance').val();
    }
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    $container.css('background',$('#color').val());
}
```

My source mainly is: https://hmp.is.it/creating-chroma-key-effect-html5-canvas/

I also tried the same using video, which works, but uses way too many client sources.

JSBin here: https://jsbin.com/bezahoziwu/edit?html,js,output Filering on this Bin doesn't work because I am guessing the image is from another url.

Comment: could you create a demo of what you have atm? Using for example jsfiddle?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, a JSBin is here: https://jsbin.com/bezahoziwu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3):

According [to specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#image-sources-for-2d-rendering-contexts:canvasimagesource-3) about the Canvas 2DRenderingContext `drawImage` method,

> Specifically, when a CanvasImageSource object represents an animated image in an HTMLOrSVGImageElement, the user agent must use the default image of the animation (the one that the format defines is to be used when animation is not supported or is disabled), or, if there is no such image, the first frame of the animation, when rendering the image for CanvasRenderingContext2D APIs.

This applies to *.gif*, SMIL animated *.svg*, CSS animated *.svg*, *.mjpeg* media and APNG. So only one frame should be drawn onto the canvas.

You would have to parse manually your APNG file and extract all the frames from there.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I coded an animated SVG generator that the user can download to SVG. There's CSS animations in SVG Style tag to animate Svg <g> and <rects> and stuff. I wanted the user to Download this as a video. To do so, I draw my SVG in a canvas to export each frame and build the video the user can download then. This works well, but I am loosing my SVG animation in the process... There's no animation anymore when appending SVG to canvas. Any idea about how to solve this ? Thank you very much

Comment: @Benjamin that would be worth its own question. I thought I saw one recently about this exact problem but I did lack time at this moment to answer it and I can't find it anymore... If by any chances it was yours, you might want to undelete it, otherwise, you might want to ask it.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido! I don't know the message you're talking about. But I've done some advanced research on exporting a CSS animated SVG to video / gif and it seems impossible. To do this, I would have to convert my CSS SVG animation to SMIL or animate it with Javascript (with GSAP for example). But I don't want that since I also want my SVG to be light to export (and without dependency), and SMIL would make it much heavier ... It is still possible for me to generate two versions: CSS animated for the SVG and SMIL animated for video export / Gif export), but it's a bit of work ...: /

Comment: @Benjamin smil wouldn't help here, as this answer says, even SMIL animations will only have their first frame painted on a canvas. Now, there are actually ways to do it, even for CSS animations) so if you want to open a new question, feel free to let me know (not much time right now to answer it, but maybe tomorrow)

Comment: thank you so much. In fact there's a hack to animate SMIL in canvas explained here: http://www.dzejkobgames.eu/how-to-export-frames-from-animated-svg. But I did'nt find any hack for CSS animations. I'll open a question and keep you in touch ! Many thanks ;)