# css svg animation works, but not when drawn on canvas, only on Firefox

Tags: css, animation, firefox, canvas, svg

I am using css to do svg animations. The goal is the make a character move on a 2d isometric grid using js.
The svg in then drawn on canvas.

My issue is, while everything works fine on Chrome :
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lunacie/SquishySlug/master/screenshots/walk-chrome.gif

It doesn't work at all on Edge, which was to be expected, as Edge doesn't support svg css animations : 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lunacie/SquishySlug/master/screenshots/walk-edge.gif

However, interestingly enough, while css svg animations seem to work on Firefox, once I draw the svg on a canvas, it stops working and gets stuck on the first frame : 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lunacie/SquishySlug/master/screenshots/walk-firefox.gif

Here is a code excerpt of how I have been doing the animations :

```
#leg_x5F_back_x5F_top {
          transform-box: fill-box;
  -webkit-animation : leg_back_top 1.5s linear infinite;
          animation : leg_back_top 1.5s linear infinite;

}
@keyframes leg_back_top {
  0% {
      -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 40%;
              transform-origin: 100% 40%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(10%, -10%) rotateZ(-10deg);
              transform: translate(10%, -10%) rotateZ(-10deg);
  }
  [...]
  80% {
      -webkit-transform-origin: 20% 40%;
              transform-origin: 20% 40%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-20%, 0%) rotateZ(30deg);
              transform: translate(-20%, 0%) rotateZ(30deg);
  }
}
```

So my question is : Is this behaviour normal and to be expected from Firefox? Maybe css animations drawn on canvas are not supported ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes chrome has a bug here. Per specs animated images should be rendered as static images on the canvas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animated PNG to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554770/animated-png-to-canvas)